# How to read a value from json output

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-facts

Basically, I need to read a value from a JSON output and use it in subsequent tasks. So, I tried `with_items`, `loop`, but nothing worked.

Sample JSON that I generated from a registered variable:

```
   TASK [local_volume_mount : debug Info from device that is parted] **************
   Monday 29 March 2021  21:33:39 +0000 (0:00:02.271)       0:00:02.417 ********** 
   ok: [node1] => {
       "partitioned_device_live_info": {
           "changed": false,
           "msg": "All items completed",
           "results": [
               {
                   "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                   "changed": false,
                   "disk": {
                       "dev": "/dev/nvme2n1",
                       "logical_block": 512,
                       "model": "SAMSUNG MZQLW960HMJP-00003",
                       "physical_block": 512,
                       "size": 937692504.0,
                       "table": "msdos",
                       "unit": "kib"
                   },
                   "failed": false,
                   "invocation": {
                       "module_args": {
                           "align": "optimal",
                           "device": "/dev/nvme2n1",
                           "flags": null,
                           "label": "msdos",
                           "name": null,
                           "number": 1,
                           "part_end": "100%",
                           "part_start": "0%",
                           "part_type": "primary",
                           "state": "present",
                           "unit": "KiB"
                       }
                   },
                   "item": [
                       {
                           "device": "/dev/nvme2n1",
                           "partitions": [
                               {
                                   "end": "100%",
                                   "number": 1,
                                   "start": "0%",
                                   "storage_class": "ssd-wkr-services"
                               }
                           ]
                       },
                       {
                           "end": "100%",
                           "number": 1,
                           "start": "0%",
                           "storage_class": "ssd-wkr-services"
                       }
                   ],
                   "partitions": [
                       {
                           "begin": 1024.0,
                           "end": 937692160.0,
                           "flags": [],
                           "fstype": "",
                           "name": "",
                           "num": 1,
                           "size": 937691136.0,
                           "unit": "kib"
                       }
                   ],
                   "script": ""
               }
           ]
       }
   }
```

So, from the above I need to read the `partitions.num` value and use it in the next task, but, I don't know how to do that.

Task:

```yaml
  - name: THIS IS BEING TESTED
    debug:
      var: "{{ item.partitions }}"
    ignore_errors: no
    #loop: "{{ partitioned_device_live_info.results }}"
    with_items: "{{ partitioned_device_live_info.results }}"
```

Output of the above task is

```
'dict object' has no attribute 'partitions'
```

I want to store that value `item.partitions.num` in a variable and then use it in further tasks.

Comment: The task you are providing here cannot give the error you are claiming it gives. `"{{ partitions }}"` can give this error. But `"{{ item.partitions }}"` would rather give `'dict object' has no attribute 'partitions'`. So you should go back to your [mre]

Comment: yes: my bad, i was running several so might have errored in pasting. updated question

Answer (score 1):

Figured out using msg, below is my change

```
  - name: THIS IS BEING TESTED with MSG and with_items
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.partitions[0].num }}"
    with_items: "{{ partitioned_device_live_info.results }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use regex in ansible to `set facts`. More details [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462580/how-do-i-use-regex-with-ansible)

Following are some use cases

```yaml
- name: Long form task does not
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /etc/hosts
    regexp: '\b(localhost)(\d*)\b'
    replace: '\1\2.localdomain\2 \1\2'

- name: Explicitly specifying positional matched groups in replacement
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^(ListenAddress[ ]+)[^\n]+$'
    replace: '\g<1>0.0.0.0'
```

Setting `fact`

```yaml
- name: set version in file after replacement
  set_fact:
    version_in_file: "{{ version_deployment_file | regex_search(docker_image_version) }}"
```

More details - [ansible.builtin.replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html)

Comment: I seriously cannot map your answer to my question at all. can you explain how your answer helps in my situation?

Comment: I see you have figured out exact mapping. For me, I use regex to fetch the facts from output, I use regex replace for changing them as per requirement.